# Windows Phone Emulator error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am getting this type of errors often. But when I restart the system and run the app again there is no problem. Whats the cause of this problem
[image]

And Visual studio says the error as this [image]sometimes this error differs...

Comment: As this works just after you restart your computer, you may just run too many programs so there's not enough RAM to run the emulator. As for the VS error, please fix the link as it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing as Harush says that your don't have enough free RAM available after you've been running the computer for a while and have many processes running. As for the second error I don't really understand from your question as to when it happens (always, randomly, or with the RAM problem?) but as the link below states it happens most often when you mess with the project file manually (when you unload and change the project in the xml editor).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dyy0x47(v=vs.90).aspx